# Dynamically import language json file for react / react-intl

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

This is the way I configure my client to render the proper language through react-intl.

```
import localeData from './translations/en.json';
//import localeData from './translations/xx.json';  <-- any language

const render = routes => {
  match({ history, routes }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <HotEnabler>
        <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={localeData}>
          <Provider store={store} app={app} restApp={restApp} key="provider">
            <Router {...renderProps} render={renderRouter} history={history}>
              {routes}
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        </IntlProvider>
      </HotEnabler>,
      dest
    );
  });
};

render(getRoutes(store));
```

However I would like to import the localeData dynamically based on the locale within a cookie. So if the locale of my user is "en", I will only load in the en.json file.

```
const locale = Cookie.get('locale') || 'en';

const render = routes => {
  match({ history, routes }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    ReactDOM.render(
      <HotEnabler>
        <IntlProvider locale={locale} messages={localeData}>
          <Provider store={store} app={app} restApp={restApp} key="provider">
            <Router {...renderProps} render={renderRouter} history={history}>
              {routes}
            </Router>
          </Provider>
        </IntlProvider>
      </HotEnabler>,
      dest
    );
  });
};

render(getRoutes(store));
```

What would be the proper way of doing this? Tried creating a function but I can't pass the data properly to messages.

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Got it solved through the following codes. Post them here in case someone needs it.

```
const languages = {
  en: require('./translations/en.json'),
  zn: require('./translations/zn.json')
};
const localeData = languages[locale];
```