# Dynamically use [lng].js in React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internationalization

I'm creating a node module for React just to try myself out and learn more. But I'm facing a problem. I want to make this module without any dependencies (except React) but I also want to have I18n in my module. I have started out like with this file structure:

```
src
|- Components
|  |- myComponent.jsx
|
|- I18n
|  |- en-us.js
|  |- sv-se.js
|
|- index.jsx
```

So I want to use the I18n js files depending on which language the user calls to the module. Here are my current files:

index.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

import Component from './Components/component';

class MyNewModule extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      greetings: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ greetings: [
      'Hola',
      'Como estas?',
      'Como te llamas?',
    ] }); // Will use props later so user can send to module
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Component greetings={this.state.greetings} locale={this.props.locale} />
    );
  }
}

export default MyNewModule;
```

myComponent.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      greetings: [],
    };

    this.getGreetings = this.getGreetings.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getGreetings();
  }

  getGreetings() {
    let greetings;

    if (props.greetings && props.greetings.length) {
      greetings = props.greetings;
    } else {
      greetings = []; // HERE I WANT TO FETCH GREETINGS FROM FILE BY props.locale
    }

    this.setState({ greetings });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.greetings.map((g, i) => {
          return (
            <div key={i}>
              {g}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

en-us.js:

```
function Lang() {
  return {
    greetings: [
      'Hello',
      'How are you?',
      'What is your name?',
    ],
  };
}

export default Lang;
```

sv-se.js

```
function Lang() {
  return {
    greetings: [
      'Hej',
      'Hur mår du?',
      'Vad heter du?',
    ],
  };
}

export default Lang;
```

As you can see I want to basically fetch the greetings from the corrent language file, depending on which locale the user use as property.

I have tried finding a good way to do this, and the only way I have found is to use `require` as stated in [Dynamically import language json file for react / react-intl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43913832/dynamically-import-language-json-file-for-react-react-intl) but I feel that there might be a better and more "reacty" way to do this.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:**

After suggestion from @Ozan Manav I changed the language files to use

```
function Lang() {
  greetings: [
    'Hello',
    'How are you?',
    'What is your name?',
  ],
}
```

and call it by using:

```
greetings = require(`./I18n/${this.props.locale}.js`).Lang.greetings;
```

but I would still like to not have to use `require` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you trying to return it as a function?

Maybe you can use as Greetings ["en-EN"] or Greetings ["sv-SE"]

```
export const Greetings = {
     "en-EN": ["Hello", "How are you?", "What is your name?"],
     "sv-SE": ["Hej", "Hur mår du?", "Vad heter du?"],
};
```

Could that be?

Comment: See my edit. I would like to have different files for each locale since I will have many more elements further on for each locale. Is this possible in any better way than my above?

Comment: Hımm, are you talking about this ?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58273043/5562701

Comment: Yes, thank you, I wonder why I didn't find that while I was googling ans searching SO. I can rewrite that solution to fit my needs :)